# symbolic links rename destination with out effecting source (xp machine)

Tags: windows-xp, symbolic-link, rename

i'm using windows XP

i have a directory with an invalid naming schame,
i would like to clone the dir (without actually coping it, as in symlinks)
and rename the files there in the proper manner for my needs.

i tired using junction.exe (from sysinternal) but renaming files in junction effects source as well. same results using linkd.exe from the resource kit.

```
any suggestions? [apparently linux allows this][1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a new directory then hardlink each file to do what you want to do. I would suggest Link Shell Extension to make this painless.

http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html